# The way to improve jQuery code performance [Selector point of view]

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to understand the best way to improve the performance of jQuery code.

Actually, I know how to cache the jQuery selectors to not touch the DOM multiple times as follow:

The worst way

```
$('.selector').text('Text');
$('.selector').text('New Text');
```

---

The better way

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.selector');
$(elem).text('Text');
$(elem).text('New Text');
```

---

The best way

```
var $elem = $('.selector');
$elem.text('Text');
$elem.text('New Text');
```

---

**First Question:** Why the third method is faster than the second, and what actually `$(elem)` do here?

**Second Question:** When I use `.data()` in jQuery, I access the internal cache, and don't touch the DOM, so what's the internal cache in JavaScript?

Comment: The second one isn't equivalent to the others, only matching first element with class `selector`, you surely mean `document.querySelectorAll('.selector')`. Anyway, if you don't have thousand of thousand elements to match, you shouldn't worry that much about performance here

Answer (score 0):

- Third is faster because you put a jQuery element into a variable (RAM) so you can access it directly and jQuery doesn't have to parse the DOM each time you want access it. Think of it like you want to edit a file, you don't want to use a search engine each time you touch it, you just let it open. In your exemple, `elem` is an HTML element and jQuery finds out wich element your referring to with `$(elem)`.
- The `.data()` method, don't touch the HTML element because it doesn't need to. It just put some data into RAM because it's faster than writing/reading it into the HTML element each time.

Comment: For the second question, what about getting the value?

Comment: You said that `.data()` will use the RAM to set the value, and I asked you, how `.data()` will **get** the value?

Comment: Well, like any other variable... Javascript stores them in RAM and get them from there. Don't you want me to explain how RAM is working?

Comment: @Peter, your second paragraph is not quite true. The getter form of `data()` reads the `data-` attributes from the DOM on first invocation, and its setter form also "touches" the DOM on first invocation (to add the expando property that keys into the global data cache).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah I'm ok with this "The getter form of data() reads the data- attributes from the DOM on first invocation". But not withe rest, the `.data()` setter never touches the element. You can do a test on this page if you want to `$('#comment-52814139').data('hello', 'world')` type this into the console, you won't see a data-hello on the `tr` element

Comment: @Peter, that's not what I meant. The setter form of `data()` will indeed not add a `data-` attribute, but it will add an expando property to the element (on first invocation) in order to associate it with the data in the global cache. That expando property has a random name (`"jQuery" + ( version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" )` to be specific) and you should find it on the element after the call to `data("hello", "world")`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh yeah right but it is store in an object then so not in DOM, right?

Comment: Well, that property is added to the DOM element, so technically it does reside in the DOM.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've done an update of my comment, is it better?

Comment: A little, but it would be clearer to state that `data()` does not create `data-` attributes (since it still touches the HTML element, technically). Also, it does not maintain the data in RAM because it is faster (since it will access the expando property, so a DOM access still occurs) but to avoid memory contention with DOM elements that cannot be freed because of the associated data (which would be the case if the data was added to the element itself).